# Refer to same input multiple times in string replacement?

Tags: python, string

I need to print something like this

```
"a=name1,b=name2,c=name1,d=name2"
```

While I have name1 and name2 in variable n1 n2

```
n1="name1"
n2="name2"
```

what I am trying to do

```
"a=%s,b=%s,c=%s,d=%s" % (n1,n2,n1,n2)
```

Is there a better way than this? way to avoid n1,n2,n1,n2 ?

with python 3 ?

and what if

```
print sys.version_info
(2, 1, 0, 'final', 0)
```

Comment: What if what? That last part doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"a=%(name1)s,b=%(name2)s,c=%(name1)s,d=%(name2)s" % {'name1': n1, 'name2': n2}
```

Comment: This is nice, Is there anything using Format & Template ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the tuple is simply duplicated you can simplify by using tuple multiplication, otherwise use the dictionary interpolation shown in the other answer or use `string.format`.

```
(n1, n2, n1, n2) == (n1, n2) * 2
```

Example of using `format`:

```
"a={0}, b={1}, c={0}, d={1}".format(name1, name2)
```

Alternatively you could use `string.replace`:

```
"a=n1, b=n2, c=n1, d=n2".replace('n1', name1).replace('n2', name2)
```

But this is error-prone, to say the least.

Comment: sorry its not repeted in any order, its a paragraph with name1 name2 repeated throughout. For brevity I have used this ex.

Comment: then there's no better way than the dictionary approach, sorry.